# How Can I Improve My CSS + HTML Workflow?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am a LAMP developer but am also advanced in CSS/HTML. The problem is that my workflow in that area really suffers from redundant and tedious tasks. There must be a better way. I currently start with the UI design and then:

- I Write the HTML
- Open BOTH the Firefox 'Web Developer' add-on's Live CSS editor AND
- Firebug CSS + HTML inspector.
- I tweak styles in Firebug and then transpose them into the Web Developer's editor (tedious!)
- Then every few iterations I copy the ENTIRE CSS from Web Developer into my text editor, save and reload the Firefox web page.

This process is OK in theory and it works for me but it requires so much window switching, and copying of style info from one app to another (Firebug to Web Developer). I could just type everything manually in Web Developer (which I sometimes do) but Firebug gives you the ability to use up/down arrows to tweak pixel settings and it auto-completes CSS key names. Seems like the ideal tool would be a hybrid of the two tools but I have not come across anything like that.

I am looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JetBrains WebStorm and its CSS XFire plug-in for Firefox and Chrome.  Once you try it, you'll never go back.

Comment: I am trying this today and will post my findings. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This was pretty much the magic bullet. Thank you! An incredibly effective solution to the CSS live updating process. Eliminates a ton of copy/pasting for me.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [FlawLESS](https://github.com/DominikGuzei/flawless.css). I put my text editor (which should support CSS very nicely) and my browser side by side and see the changes instantly.

Comment: Very interesting framework. Not sure that I want the learning curve associated with less.js right now although it does look super-cool.

Comment: Well the good thing about less as a language is that it's optional. It has fully backward compatible syntax to CSS - so you don't have to use it if you don't want to ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use both Firebug and the Web Developer control to edit the live css.  You can do both from firebug, just click on the css tab, and click edit.  Typically I don't even bother to change the css the firebug edit pane though.  I use the style pane and each time I make a tweak I am happy with I put it right in the real css file.

Comment: You can't save the edits made in firebug, as changes, to your CSS file.

Comment: ohh cool I was not aware you could save directly from the web developer thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using something like git? There was actually a pretty good beginner tutorial on it recently over at *A List Apart: [Getting Started with Git](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/get-started-with-git/)*.

With version control you can just work locally, and pushing your latest stable code to the live site is always a few clicks away.